# Jinja2 get list item by attribute

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I'm trying to grab an item from a list my jinja2 code like how I would in Python:

`{% set node=next(node for node in slide.nodes if node.index==2) %}`

but I get the following error: `TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'for'`

Is this not achievable in Jinja2?

Comment: The docs specifically say that ["advanced expressions such as list comprehensions and generator expressions are not supported."](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/faq/).  Perhaps write a filter or a global function?

Comment: As you suggest, I wrote a python function `provide_node` which is called my jinja template. But the function doesn't recognize the nodes in `slide.nodes` to have a `index` attribute.

Python output:
`[{u'index': 1, u'style': {}, u'resource': None}, {u'index': 2, u'style': {}, u'resource': None}, {u'index': 3, u'style': {}, u'resource': None}]`

Python error:
`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'index'`

Comment: Jinja is more like javascript in that it treads "x.foo" as the same thing as "x['foo']".  In your python function, you'll need to use the latter version if you are passing dictionaries to it.

Comment: it works thank you!

Comment: how about `slide.nodes | selectattr("index", "eq", 2) | first`